# kivy garden graph issue Command failed: garden install --app grap

Tags: python, graph, kivy

When trying to debug and generate my apk, this error happens. If comment out garden requirements in buildozer.spec, it builds up but does not deploy on android, due to same issues with garden graph.

Is it outdated ??

Downloading http://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/archive/master.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/musarra/Desktop/musarrapc/docs/pyproj/yfacereal/.buildozer/venv/bin/garden", line 189, in 
    GardenTool().main(sys.argv[1:])

File "/home/musarra/Desktop/musarrapc/docs/pyproj/yfacereal/.buildozer/venv/bin/garden", line 71, in main
    options.func()

File "/home/musarra/Desktop/musarrapc/docs/pyproj/yfacereal/.buildozer/venv/bin/garden", line 109, in cmd_install
    fd = self.download(opts.package)

File "/home/musarra/Desktop/musarrapc/docs/pyproj/yfacereal/.buildozer/venv/bin/garden", line 170, in download
    data += buf

TypeError: must be str, not bytes

## Command failed: garden install --app graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is outdated, the way of calling garden in `.spec` file has changed.

Try adding garden dependency to requirements part as follows:

```
requirements = sqlite3,kivy,kivy_garden.graph
```